# Why is my batch file not processing last conditional statement?

Tags: batch-file

I get all the way to the end of my batch file, to the "test" echo.  Then the script bombs out.  It never makes it to the "test1" statement.  I am uncertain as to why this would be since the conditional command is near identical to the previous command that worked.

Here is my code.  I have commented out the commands that will edit your registry so that you can safely run this script.  The same behavior occurs.

```
@echo OFF

echo A "feature" in Windows 7 may cause problems for some programs in 
echo certain conditions. 
echo.
echo Basically, if you have a high resolution screen at install time, Win7 will 
echo install a larger font set (125%) by default. If you then choose go back to the 
echo standard font size (100%), Windows will keep some of the large fonts even 
echo though everything else is adjusted for standard fonts, causing programs that 
echo use these fonts to break because the text will not always fit inside the GUI. 
echo.
echo.

for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set VERSION=%%i.%%j

if "%version%" == "6.1" (
    echo Verified Windows 7 system
    echo.
) else (
    echo This is not a Windows 7 system.
    goto end
)


setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

::variable used for validation logic
set fontsExist=true

:: Sets the Registry Key Name
set KEY_NAME="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts"

:: Sets the Registry Sub Key Names
set COURIER_VALUE_NAME="Courier 10,12,15"
set MS_SANS_SERIF_VALUE_NAME="MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24"
set MS_SERIF_VALUE_NAME="MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24"

:: Queries the registry for the Courier 10,12,15 font and saves the data
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-6" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %COURIER_VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set COURIER_ValueName=%%A %%B
    set COURIER_ValueType=%%C
    set COURIER_ValueValue=%%D
)

if defined COURIER_ValueName (
    @echo Courier 10,12,15 Value Name = %COURIER_ValueName%
    @echo Courier 10,12,15 Value Type = %COURIER_ValueType%
    @echo Courier 10,12,15 Value Value = %COURIER_ValueValue%
    echo.
) else (
    @echo %KEY_NAME%\%COURIER_VALUE_NAME% not found.
    echo.
    set fontsExist=false
)

FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-6" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %MS_SANS_SERIF_VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set MS_SANS_SERIF_ValueName=%%A %%B %%C %%D
    set MS_SANS_SERIF_ValueType=%%E
    set MS_SANS_SERIF_ValueValue=%%F
)

if defined MS_SANS_SERIF_ValueName (
    @echo MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 Value Name = %MS_SANS_SERIF_ValueName%
    @echo MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 Value Type = %MS_SANS_SERIF_ValueType%
    @echo MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 Value Value = %MS_SANS_SERIF_ValueValue%
    echo.
) else (
    @echo %KEY_NAME%\%MS_SANS_SERIF_VALUE_NAME% not found.
    echo.
    set fontsExist=false
)

FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-5" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %MS_SERIF_VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set MS_SERIF_ValueName=%%A %%B %%C
    set MS_SERIF_ValueType=%%D
    set MS_SERIF_ValueValue=%%E
)

if defined MS_SERIF_ValueName (
    @echo MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 Value Name = %MS_SERIF_ValueName%
    @echo MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 Value Type = %MS_SERIF_ValueType%
    @echo MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 Value Value = %MS_SERIF_ValueValue%
    echo.
) else (
    @echo %KEY_NAME%\%MS_SERIF_VALUE_NAME% not found.
    echo.
    set fontsExist=false
)

if fontExists==false (
    echo Not all fonts exist.
    echo.
    goto end
)

echo If you want to write to your registry then
pause
echo.

:courier_eval

::checks for correct values
if %COURIER_ValueValue%==COURF.FON (
    echo Courier 10,12,15 registry key is correct.
    goto san_eval
)

::checks for known incorrect values
if %COURIER_ValueValue%==COURE.FON (
    echo COURIER font registry value is incorrect.  Attempting to correct...
    ::REG ADD %KEY_NAME% /v %COURIER_VALUE_NAME% /t "%COURIER_ValueType%" /d "COURE.FON" /f
    goto san_eval
)

:san_eval

::checks for correct values
if %MS_SANS_SERIF_ValueValue%==SSERIFF.FON (
    echo MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 registry key is correct.
    goto serif_eval
)

::checks for known incorrect values
if %MS_SANS_SERIF_ValueValue%==SSERIFE.FON (
    echo MS SANS SERIF font registry value is incorrect.  Attempting to correct...
    ::REG ADD %KEY_NAME% /v %MS_SANS_SERIF_VALUE_NAME% /t "%MS_SANS_SERIF_ValueType%" /d "SSERIFE.FON" /f
    goto serif_eval
)
:serif_eval

::checks for correct values
if %MS_SERIF_ValueValue%==SERIFF.FON (
    echo MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 registry key is correct.
    goto end
)
echo test
pause

::checks for known incorrect values
if %MS_SERIF_ValueValue%==SERIFE.FON (
    echo MS SERIF font registry value is incorrect.  Attempting to correct...
    ::REG ADD %KEY_NAME% /v %MS_SERIF_VALUE_NAME% /t "%MS_SERIF_ValueType%" /d "SERIFE.FON" /f
)
echo test1
pause
:end

pause
```

The code in question is between `echo test` and `echo test1` near the end.

Comment: Bravo for commenting-out. Problem is that `::` comment-style tends to break code blocks - use `rem` instead. You say that `test1` is not reached, but you don't say which of `test` or  `MS SERIF font registry value is incorrect.  Attempting to correct...` is reached, nor you do state what the value of `MS_SERIF_ValueValue` or any other variable is. Please clarify.

Comment: Well, I did not know that about the `::` comment style.  I have changed all of those to `rem`, and the problem has now disappeared.  Please post that as an answer and I will indicate that your answer solved the problem.

Comment: BTW the commented out `Reg ADD` would put the same  data `SERIFE.FON` you state known incorrect? IMO a better way would be to check for the proper files being present and Import a reg file previously saved or from an other pc.

Comment: @LotPings  Good advice.  I am still working on exactly what the registry changes need to be.  For now, I am just setting up a working logic structure.

Comment: Please consult the following help topic: [mcve]. Read at least the [tour]...

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that :: comment-style tends to break code blocks - use rem instead.